# Passing a struct to pthread_create()

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, struct, pthreads

Here's a function that should recursively find more precise values of Pi and split into a user defined amount of threads to do the recursion concurrently.

```
void* quad(void* argis){
    struct args* arg=argis;

    double m=(arg->l+arg->r)/2;
    double fm=func(m);
    double larea=(arg->fl+fm)*(m-arg->l)/2;
    double rarea = (fm+arg->fr)*(arg->r-m)/2;

    struct args* arg1 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg1->l=arg->l;
    arg1->r=m;
    arg1->fl=arg->fl;
    arg1->fr=fm;
    arg1->area=larea;

    struct args* arg2 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg2->l=m;
    arg2->r=arg->r;
    arg2->fl=fm;
    arg2->fr=arg->fl;
    arg2->area=rarea;

    if(fabs((larea+rarea)-arg->area)>error){
        if(threads<=1){
            void* p1=quad((void*)arg1);
            void* p2=quad((void*)arg2);
            larea=*((double*)p1);
            rarea=*((double*)p2);
            free(p1);
            free(p2);


        }
        else{
            pthread_t thread1, thread2;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            threads--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

            pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &quad, (void*)&arg1);
            pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &quad, (void*)&arg2);

            void* ptr1;
            void* ptr2;

            pthread_join(thread1,&ptr1);
            pthread_join(thread2,&ptr2);


            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            threads++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

            larea=*(double*)ptr1;
            rarea=*(double*)ptr2;


        }
    }
    free(arg1);
    free(arg2);

    double ret= (larea+rarea);
    double* poin=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    *poin=ret;

    return (void*)poin;
}
```

However, it doesn't work. After investigating I've found that the problem seems to be here:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &quad, (void*)&arg1);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &quad, (void*)&arg2);
```

All arguments in struct `arg1` and `arg2` just become 0 after they've been passed in to the new thread. `arg1` and `arg2` aren't local they're in heap and I'm pretty sure threads share heap so that's not the problem. Is this not how you pass arguments to new thread in `pthread_create()`?

This is my first time working with pthreads so be patient with me. But any help finding out what's causing the structs to be reset would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It is missing a `main()` function, it is missing the necessary `#include` statements..   It is also very recursive and will generate many many many threads.   Also note, exiting a thread should be done via a call to `pthread_exit()`

Comment: BTW, when taking the address of a function, the "address of" (i.e. `&`) operator is unnecessary, so `pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, quad, arg1)` is preferred.

Comment: @user3629249 `pthread_exit` is optional. The `void *` return works just fine. The analogy is `main`: It can exit via `exit(1)` or just a `return 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `arg1` and `arg2` *are* pointers already you want to pass them to to `pthread_create()` "as is":

```
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &quad, arg1);
```

---

Also there is no need to cast here:

```
  void* p1=quad((void*)arg1);
```

Just do:

```
  void* p1=quad(arg1);
```

---

Same for `malloc()`, no need to cast its result.

Nor here:

```
  return (void*)poin;
```

Doing

```
  return poin;
```

is fine.

In C conversion of any pointer to/from `void*` is done implicitly.

Comment: Yup, that was it! Though it's running slower with two threads than with one. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, some thoughts: 1) threads require context swapping, which takes time 2) the code (when the variable `threads` is >1) is massively recursive and spawns many more threads. That recursion and the spawning of more threads takes time